# Does the Raiden client ever deploy TokenNetworkRegistry?

Tags: raiden

Is there any code in the [Raiden client](https://github.com/raiden-network/raiden) that deploys a TokenNetworkRegistry contract?

Answer (score 0):

The client, generally, will not deploy a new token network registry. Through the REST and Python APIs it may register a new token with an existing registry, but the deployment of the registry is done without the client.

With that said, it is possible for a user to run Raiden with the console interface and the use the existing code to deploy any smart contract. There is code to [deploy smart contracts](https://github.com/raiden-network/raiden/blob/864348c785276b724b1c9c7bbf4523150335c558/raiden/network/rpc/client.py#L549-L589) in the JSONRPCClient class.